# QML: contentItem does not show any Image

Tags: qml, qt5

I am using `QML` to design a small user interface.

**The problem** I have is that I need to select an image if a certain conditions happens or not, and nothing happens because I may have something wrong in the `contentItem` below, I set a simple a `if` loop that replicates exactly the problem I have:

**main.qml**

```
// operations ....

Row {
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.leftMargin: 20
    anchors.topMargin: 20
    Button {
        id: button
        width: 90
        height: 270

        contentItem: Item {
            Image {
                source: root.selected === 0 ?
                    source: "qrc:/images/btn-Modes-on.png" :
                    source: "qrc:/images/btn-modes-normal.png"
            }
        }
// operations ....

}
```

I believe the problem is where I set the `if` loop for the images. I can confirm that the path of the images is correct and double checked.
I also used according to the documentation the proper notation of the images, and the property I am using is `source: "path to your image"`.
However after checking that I still also have no return.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "if loop". But it looks like you have a typo in your `source` line. You shouldn't have `source:` for each part of the conditional statement. It should just look like this: `source: root.selected === 0 ? "qrc:/images/btn-Modes-on.png" : "qrc:/images/btn-modes-normal.png"`

Comment: :) Thanks for catching that! that works! If you write the answer I can accept it :) . Thanks for stopping by and reading the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in your code. The Image source should look like this:

```
source: root.selected === 0 ? 
    "qrc:/images/btn-Modes-on.png" : 
    "qrc:/images/btn-modes-normal.png"
```